# Stop Duplicate Ajax Submisions?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am wondering what is the best way to stop duplciate submissions when using jquery and ajax?

I come up with 2 possible ways but not sure if these are the only 2.

1. On Ajax start disable all buttons till request is done. 2 problems I see with this though is I use jquery model dialog so I don't know how easy it would be to disable those button as I not sure if they have id's. Second I if the the request hangs the user has really no way to try again since all the buttons are disabled.
2. I am looking into something called AjaxQueue at this time I have no clue if it is what I need or how it works since the site where the plugin is apparently down for maintenance.

http://docs.jquery.com/AjaxQueue

**Edit**

I think this is a spin off of what I was looking at.

http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/

The only problem I see with this ajaxManager is that I think I have to change all my $.post, $.get and $.ajax ones to their type.

But what happens if I need a special parameter from $.ajax? Or that fact I like using .post and .get.

**Edit 2**

I think it can take in all $.ajax options. I am still looking into it. However what I am unsure about now is can I use the same constructor for all requests that will use the same options.

```
First you have to construct/configure a new Ajaxmanager
//create an ajaxmanager named someAjaxProfileName
var someManagedAjax = $.manageAjax.create('someAjaxProfileName', {
    queue: true, 
    cacheResponse: true
});
```

Or do I have to make the above every single time?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about setting a flag when the user clicks the button? You will only clear the flag when the AJAX request completes successfully (in `complete`, which is called after the `success` and `error` callbacks), and you will only send an AJAX request if the flag is not set.

Related to AJAX queuing there is a plugin called [jQuery Message Queuing](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-message-queuing/docs/files/jquery-ba-jqmq-js.html) that is very good. I've used it myself.

```
var requestSent = false;

jQuery("#buttonID").click(function() {   
   if(!requestSent) {
      requestSent = true;

      jQuery.ajax({
         url: "http://example.com",
         ....,
         timeout: timeoutValue,
         complete: function() {
             ...
             requestSent = false;
         },
      });
   }
});
```

You can set a timeout value for long-running requests (value is in milliseconds) if you think your request has a possibility of hanging. If an timeout occurs, the `error` callback is called, after which the `complete` callback gets called.

Answer (score 9):

You could store an active request in a variable, then clear it when there's a response.

```
var request;  // Stores the XMLHTTPRequest object

$('#myButton').click(function() {
    if(!request) {  // Only send the AJAX request if there's no current request 

        request = $.ajax({  // Assign the XMLHTTPRequest object to the variable
            url:...,
            ...,
            complete: function() { request = null } // Clear variable after response
        });

    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

One nice thing about this, is that you could cancel long running requests using `abort()`.

```
var request;  // Stores the XMLHTTPRequest object
var timeout;  // Stores timeout reference for long running requests

$('#myButton').click(function() {
    if(!request) {  // Only send the AJAX request if there's no current request 

        request = $.ajax({  // Assign the XMLHTTPRequest object to the variable
            url:...,
            ...,
            complete: function() { timeout = request = null } // Clear variables after response
        });

        timeout = setTimeout( function() {
                        if(request) request.abort();  // abort request
                  }, 10000 );                         //   after 10 seconds

    }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't using the `timeout` property be easier? Or does it not work the way I think it does? :)

Comment: @Vivin - Good point. Unless there's some other logic that you want to use in the `setTimeout()` to decide whether or not to abort, you could use the `timeout` property. The `request` variable is a flag like in your answer, but with the added benefit of providing `abort()` functionality if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.xhrPool = {};
$.xhrPool['hash'] = []
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR,settings) {
        var hash = settings.url+settings.data
        if ( $.xhrPool['hash'].indexOf(hash) === -1 ){
            jqXHR.url   = settings.url;
            jqXHR.data  = settings.data;
            $.xhrPool['hash'].push(hash);
        }else{
            console.log('Duplicate request cancelled!');
            jqXHR.abort();
        }
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR,settings) {
        var hash = jqXHR.url+jqXHR.data 
            if (index > -1) {
                $.xhrPool['hash'].splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

heres a "return method"

it will not execute the ajax code again until it is done processing

```
var firstenter = true;

jQuery("#buttonID").click(function() { 
  if (!firstenter){
     return;
  }
  firstenter = false;
  jQuery.ajax({
     url: "http://example.com",
     ....,
     timeout: timeoutValue,
     complete: function() {
         ...
         firstenter = true;
     },
  });
});
```